# Watermark asp:Login control Username and Password fields

Tags: asp.net, jquery, authentication, watermark

I'm trying to watermark the asp:Login controls' Username and Password fields with jQuery, I've tried various ways of referencing the control ID:

```
$('#<%=ClientID.Login1_UserName %>').watermark('watermark', 'Username');
```

I have tried moving the ClientID, Login1 and UserName around and changing the selectors to and from userscores and periods...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good old jQuery selectors ;)

```
$("input[name*='UserName']").watermark('watermark', 'Username');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[id$='_UserName']:first").watermark('watermark', 'Username');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Login1_UserName" ... >
```

then your jquery code needs to look something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= Login1_UserName.ClientID %>').watermark('watermark', 'Username');
    }
// -->
</script>
```

although @Gogster had a very good suggestion as well--to avoid the <% %> tags altogether, which in my opinion is a bit more elegant and no less difficult to understand.

Comment: I agree k.robinson, although I am agreeing with myself and you!) also the code tags cause problems with validation.